# Backpropagation keras source code

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow

I searched for the backpropagation code in keras github but I couldn't find it. Searched [model.fit()](https://github.com/kerasteam/keras/blob/v2.12.0/keras/engine/training.py#L1338)
Please help. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In Keras, the backpropagation algorithm is not explicitly written as a separate function or method. Instead, it's implemented as part of the training process when we use `model.fit()`. The backpropagation algorithm is handled by TensorFlow's automatic differentiation and optimization features. When using Keras, we typically define our model architecture, compile the model with a chosen optimizer and loss function, and then train the model using model.fit(). The optimizer and loss function are the key components that enable the backpropagation process.

let's say if we are using the popular Adam optimizer, Keras relies on TensorFlow's `tf.keras.optimizers.Adam` implementation. The backpropagation process is handled by the optimizer when it updates the model weights based on the gradients of the loss function with respect to the weights.

Comment: Decent information. Even better would be to show the auto-diff code for one of the examples you cite.

Comment: Do you mean I should demonstrate the backpropagation process?

Comment: I'm suggesting to answer the question by showing the where the `auto-diff` source is

Comment: @Rohit Singh Ok backprop is handled by the `keras.optimizers.Optimizer` , but that will have the backdrop code (even though not as a separate method) right, I'm asking for that.